# Google Chrome Extension (v.17)

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to made a simple google chrome extension using webRequest and onCompleted listener. When all the info is loaded i want to show an alert message, but is not working :(

**Manifest**

```
    {
      "name": "Test",
      "version": "0.1",
      "minimum_chrome_version": "10.0",
      "description": "Test Google Chrome Extension",
      "background_page": "background.html",
      "permissions": [
        "webRequest",
        "*://*/*"
      ],
      "content_security_policy": "default-src 'self'"
    }
```

**Background.html**

```
    chrome.webRequest.onCompleted.addListener(
       function(details) {
          alert(details.url);
       },
       {urls: ["*://*/*"]},
       ["requestHeaders"]
    );
```

***Solution***

I solved the problem :)
I changed the line "requestHeaders" to "responseHeaders".

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to change the line ["requestHeaders"] to ["responseHeaders"].

**New Background**

```
chrome.webRequest.onCompleted.addListener(
   function(details) {
      alert(details.url);
   },
   {urls: ["*://*/*"]},
   ["requestHeaders"]
);
```